# The endomorphism structure on a free group thinks it's a "ring" without abelian $+$, but there's no way it could be a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, group-homomorphism, free-groups

Let $G$ be a free group on a finite alphabet $A$, and $R = \text{End}(G)$.  Then we can concatenate endmorphisms pointwise to get another one. But endomorphisms preserve concatenation so this must mean that $f \circ (g \cdot h) = (f\circ g) \cdot (f\circ h)$ and similarly for $(g\cdot h) \circ f$.  But, the multiplicative identity would be $\text{id} \in R$, and for certain when $|A| \geq 2$, $G$ is not a commutative group.

So I don't know what is going on.  I would like there to be some sort of ring-like structure, but this contradicts known observations.

Comment: Concatenation of two endomorphisms is not necessarily an endomorphism. Say $A=\{x,y\}$, $g$ sends $x$ to $x^2$ and $y$ to $y^2$, and $h$ swaps $x$ and $y$, extended via the universal property. Then the concatenation sends $x$ to $xxy$, and sends $x^{-1}$ to $x^{-2}y^{-1}$. But then $(g\cdot h)(x^{-1})\neq ((g\cdot h)(x))^{-1}$.

Comment: Interesting to see you are so happy about putting down the free group by saying it can't ever be a ring (the emoji)

Comment: Would you explain, in detail, what is the operation of "concatenating endomorphisms"? You input two endomorphisms $g,h \in \text{End}(G)$ and output... what? I think you don't mean composition $g \circ h \in \text{End}(G)$ because you use a single dot $g \cdot h$, but then I do not understand what $g \cdot h \in \text{End}(G)$ is supposed to be.

Comment: @LeeMosher pointwise op on functions is $(f\cdot g)(x) = f(x)\cdot g(x)$.

Comment: Well in that case the comment of @ArturoMagidin holds, $f \cdot g \not\in \text{End}(G)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then we can concatenate endmorphisms pointwise to get another one.

This is where you go wrong. You don’t necessarily get another one unless the group is commutative.

For suppose $f \cdot g$ is a group homomorphism. Then $(f(a) g(a))^{-1} = g(a)^{-1} f(a)^{-1}$ by the normal group laws, but because $f \cdot g$ is an endormorphism, we also have $(f(a) g(a))^{-1} = f(a^{-1}) g(a^{-1}) = f(a)^{-1} g(a)^{-1}$. Then we have that $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ commute for all $a$. Obviously, this is not true in general.

For an Abelian group, we do indeed get a not-necessarily-commutative unital ring.